# C# Surface (WPF) / Soundeffects -> Dictionary<String,MediaElement>

Tags: c#, mediaelement, pixelsense, soundeffect

due to the lack of Sound Effects in Microsoft Surface Applications I tried to built a "Sound bank" with sound files (.wav) in a Dictionary.

The sound file is short.

path = PathToFile

My "Sound bank":

```
Dictionary<string, MediaElement> soundBank = new Dictionary<string, MediaElement>(29);
soundBank = new Dictionary<string, MediaElement>(20);
        soundBank.Add("1", new MediaElement());
        soundBank.Add("2", new MediaElement());
        soundBank.Add("3", new MediaElement());
        soundBank.Add("4", new MediaElement());
        soundBank.Add("A", new MediaElement());
        soundBank.Add("BE", new MediaElement());
        soundBank.Add("CF", new MediaElement());
...

foreach (var item in soundBank)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
            //soundBank[item.Key] = new MediaElement();
            soundBank[item.Key].Source = new Uri(path);
            soundBank[item.Key].LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
            soundBank[item.Key].UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
            soundBank[item.Key].Volume = 1;
            soundBank[item.Key].MediaEnded += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(mp_MediaEnded);
```

If I try to play multiple sounds (on_button_click) the sounds are delayed or simply do not play:

```
public void play(string key)
    {

        soundBank[key].Stop();
        soundBank[key].Play();

    }
    void mp_MediaEnded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MediaElement)e.Source).Stop();
    }
```

SoundPlayer and MediaPlayer are not suited, because they stop all other played sounds.

Comment: Tried DirectX ? or is it too big of a gun?

Comment: New DirectX Version does not support managed code (c#)!? I didn't find examples (neither doc nor google fitting my purpose)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11184/The-ultimate-Managed-DirectSound-9-Tutorial-Part-1   tutorial on DSound9

i used it in game dev, but should be suitable for you too,  though it will make your code FAT :)

Comment: So I have to install DirectX9 SDK... I'll try it thank you. I'll report ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I use IrrKlang now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the [irrKlang library](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/index.html) now for my project:

It is very very easy to use:

```
using IrrKlang;
...

ISoundEngine engine = new ISoundEngine();

...

engine.Play2D(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\sound.wav");
```

Ultimately simple solution ^^

Comment: does IrrKlang cache the sound.wav  or load it from disk each time??? 
though for simple apps it doesnt matter, is interesting.

Comment: IrrKlang handles everything for you (http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/docu/index.html#features). It caches the sound automatically :)